# Universal first countability in ZF?

Tags: general-topology, logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

It's easy to come up with examples of spaces which are provably-in-ZFC not first countable: e.g. the order topology on $\omega_1+1$, or the cocountable topology on any uncountable set. However, these proofs tend to rely on principles of the form "every 'small' union of 'small' sets is 'small'," and [these can fail quite badly without choice](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02760939).

Conversely, at the other end of things, if we extend ZF by a strong *anti*-choice principle, we can often get provably non-first-countable spaces. For example, the cofinite topology on an amorphous set $A$ is non-first-countable.

*Why? Pick $a\in A$, and consider a sequence $(U_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of neighborhoods of $a$. The union of the complements of the $U_i$s must not be finite in order for the sequence to witness first countability. Let $V_i$ be the set of points "thrown out for the first time" at stage $i$: that is, $V_i$ is the set of $y$ such that $y\not\in U_i$ but $y\in \bigcup_{j<i} U_j$. Infinitely many of the $V_i$s must be nonempty; WLOG suppose each $V_i$ is nonempty. But then $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}V_{2i}$ and $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}V_{2i+1}$ are two disjoint infinite subsets of $A$.*

So my question is whether we can find non-first-countable spaces in ZF alone. Phrased most simply, this is:

> Does ZF prove that there are non-first-countable spaces?

We can also ask a question which might be a bit more satisfying:

> Is there a formula $\varphi$ which ZF proves defines a non-first-countable topological space?

I suspect that the answer to even the first question is "no," and that this is witnessed in something like Gitik's model; but I'm not sure.

Comment: In Gitik's model, if I recall correctly, every set is the countable union of smaller sets. That should serve as a counterexample. I could ask him, he's sitting right here...

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am aware of that property of Gitik's model, which is why I thought it might give a counterexample, but I didn't see how to apply it immediately; and Eric's answer shows there's a reason for that!

Comment: What about $\mathbb N$ with the topology $$\tau=\{U\subseteq\mathbb N: 1\notin U\text{ or }U\text{ has natural density one}\}?$$ Am I missing some subtle use of the axiom of choice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $X=\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$, topologized such that a nonempty set is open iff it contains $\infty$ and contains cofinitely many points of $\{n\}\times\mathbb{N}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  Then $X$ is not first-countable at $\infty$.  Indeed, suppose $(U_n)$ is a local base at $\infty$.  For each $n$, let $j_n$ be the least $j$ such that $(n,j)\in U_n$ (since $U_n$ is nonempty and open, it must contain $(n,j)$ for all but finitely many $j$).  Now let $$U=\{\infty\}\cup\{(n,j)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}:j>j_n\}.$$ Then $U$ is an open neighborhood of $\infty$.  However, $U$ does not contain any $U_n$, since for each $n$, $(n,j_n)\in U_n$ but $(n,j_n)\not\in U$.

This is not just a pathological example--similar examples come up very naturally when you glue together infinitely many spaces at a point, for instance, when considering non-locally finite CW complexes in algebraic topology.  As a very concrete example, a wedge sum of countably infinitely many copies of $[0,1]$ can be proven (in ZF) to not be first-countable at the basepoint by essentially the same argument.

Comment: Nice example - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Topologize $\mathbb N$ so that a subset $U$ of $\mathbb N$ is open if either $1\notin U$ or else $\sum\{\frac1n:n\in\mathbb N\setminus U\}\lt\infty.$
I claim that there is no countable base for the neighborhoods of $1.$

Suppose $U_1,U_2,U_3,\dots$ is an infinite sequence of open sets containing $1.$ For each index $i,$ since $U_i$ is an infinite set, we can define $n_i$ as the least element of $U_i$ which exceeds $2^i.$ Then, since $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac1{n_i}\lt\sum_{i=1}^\infty2^{-i}\lt\infty,$ the set $U=\mathbb N\setminus\{n_1,n_2,n_3,\dots\}$ is an open set containing $1;$ and for each $i$ we have $U_i\not\subseteq U$ since $n_i\in U_i\setminus U.$