# Example of non metrizable topological groups satisfying an extra condition.

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, topological-groups

> **DEFINITION-**  A function $f:X \to Y$ is called D-supercontinuous if inverse image of every open set is open $F_{\sigma}$ set.

I am looking for an example of a non metrizable topological group (Hausdorff) in which the group operations are also D-supercontinuous.

Obviously every metric group is such a group but I am having a hard time finding a nontrivial or non metric topological group. I know it must not be second countable.

Any help to point me in the right direction is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The point being: in a non-metric space, there could be open sets that are not $F_\sigma$ sets.  An example of a non-metric topological group:  $\mathbb T^A$ where $\mathbb T = \mathbb R/\mathbb Z$  and $A$ is an uncountable set.  I do not know if this is D-supercontinuous, but maybe we should attempt to find out.

Comment: More simply, you just want a non-metrizable topological group in which every open set is $F_\sigma$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ with the weak topology, i.e. the colimit of the sequence of inclusions $\mathbb{R}^0\to\mathbb{R}^1\to\mathbb{R}^2\to\dots$ (concretely, $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is the set of finite-support sequences of real numbers, with the topology that a set is open iff its intersection with $\mathbb{R}^n$ is open for each $n$).  This is a topological group with respect to coordinatewise addition (this is not obvious--to prove addition is continuous, you have to show $\mathbb{R}^\infty\times\mathbb{R}^\infty$ also has the weak topology; see for instance Theorem A.6 in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*).  It is not first countable and thus not metrizable (again, this is not obvious--you can use an argument similar to the argument in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2381572/86856), picking sequences converging to $0$ along each coordinate axis).  However, every open subset of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is $F_{\sigma}$: an open set is the union of its intersections with $\mathbb{R}^n$ for each $n$, and the intersection with $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and thus a countable union of closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, which are then also closed in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$.

Comment: To find such a topological ring, I can just add trivial multiplication operation to $R^{\infty}$? Correct?

Comment: Can you give me some reference to some book or link where I can read more about this space and the topology you mentioned on it?

Comment: Sure, if you don't require your rings to have unit.   If you want a unital ring then you could give $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ the ring structure of a polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$, for instance.  I don't know a reference about this space particularly but colimit constructions like this are used all the time in algebraic topology (usually in the form of CW-complexes), for instance as discussed in the appendix to Hatcher's Algebraic Topology.

Comment: So  $R^{\infty}$ is a non-metrizable topological group in which every open set is $F_{\sigma}$. Are there anymore such examples, which are easier to understand. I am not versed in algebraic topology.

Comment: Also can you tell whether $R^{\infty}$ is connected or disconnected?

Comment: It should be connected, being countable product of connected spaces, right?

Comment: It is not a countable product of connected spaces (it has only the finite-support sequences), but it is connected.

Comment: In similar fashion, $C^{\infty}$ should work too, right?

Comment: You mean a colimit of $\mathbb{C}^0\to\mathbb{C}^1\to\mathbb{C}^2\to\dots$?  That's the same thing as $\mathbb{R}^\infty$, since $\mathbb{C}^n$ is just $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

Comment: Sure, that's fine.